# java.lang.ClassCastException at runtime

Tags: java, type-conversion

I'm getting a ClassCastException in the follow code:

```
Destination[] destinations;
ArrayList<Destination> destinationsList = new ArrayList<Destination>(); 

// .....

destinations = (Destination[]) destinationsList.toArray();
```

My Destination class looks like this:

```
public class Destination {

    private String code;

    Destination (String code) {

        this.code = code;

    }

   public String getCode () {

        return code;

   }
}
```

Syntactically I'm not getting any errors, this only occurs at run time. It's confuzing though because aren't all classes essentially derivatives of the Object class? And if so, why does this cast conversion error even occur?

Comment: Use the overloaded version of `toArray`.

Comment: «aren't all classes essentially derivatives of the Object class?» This means everything can be casted to `Object`, not that `Object` can be casted to everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because toArray returns an object array not your `Destination[]`

replace it with this

```
destinations[] = destinationsList.toArray(new Destination[destinationList.size()]);
```

this would populate the new Destination Array object and return the populated array.

**Edit:**

To answer your question in comment in @ZouZou's answer.

you need the `new Destination[]` because a `Destination[]` can be referred by a `Object[]` but the other way round is not possible.

to clarify things,

```
String s = "hello";
Object o = s;
s = (String) o; //works

//but

String s = "hello";
Object o = s;
o = new Object;
s = (String) o; //gives you a ClassCastException because an Object
                //cannot be referred by a string
```

> Because a String has all the properties defined in the `Object` class through inheritence but an Object doesn't possess the properties of a `String` object. That is why it is legal to cast up the inheritence tree and downcasting is not.

Comment: So casting the way I did e.g. '(Destination[])' would never work why?

Comment: Ah! Lightbulb! That's what I didn't understand and take into account. The inheritance tree, thank you very much that makes sense now.

Comment: glad i was of help.. :)

Answer (score 6):

`toArray()` returns an `Object[]`. What you need is [`toArray(T[] a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) because of the type erasure, a generic collection cannot create a typed array.

By using the overloaded method, you can help it to create a typed array of `Destination` objects.

Use

`destinations = destinationsList.toArray(new Destination[destinationList.size()]);`

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly! But still.. I don't get why you need to do it this way, toArray() returns an Object[] , you then just cast that Object[] to a Destination[].. What's all that T[] a stuff all about?

Comment: One more thing: Since toArray() returns an Object[] and I want it to be stored in a Destination[] variable, isn't that what the type casting is FOR?? I understand what you're saying, but why didn't it work the way I did it? Do I have the wrong understanding of type casting then in general?

Comment: @Relborg You can't cast the `Object[]` array returned by `toArray()` to a `Destination[]` array b'coz the actual array being created by `toArray()` is an `Object[]`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not implemented on the language level because of how generics are put in the language. Also do not try something like this :

```
// Destination[] destinations;
    ArrayList<Destination> destinationsList = new ArrayList<Destination>();
    //add some destinations
    destinationsList.add(new Destination("1"));
    destinationsList.add(new Destination("2"));
    // .....
    Object[] destinations = destinationsList.toArray();
    destinations[1] = "2"; //simulate switching of one object in the converted array with object that is of other type then Destination
    for (Object object : destinations) {
        //we want to do something with Destionations
        Destination destination = (Destination) object;
        System.out.println(destination.getCode()); //exception thrown when second memeber of the array is processed
    }
```

Use this :

```
destinations = destinationsList.toArray(new Destination[0]); //yes use 0
```